Google Auth libraries conflicts with Ionic
I have tried to implement this:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/migrate-v1
Error: Module not found: Error: Can’t resolve ‘http’

[ng] BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.

[ng] This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

[ng] If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:

[ng] - add a fallback ‘resolve.fallback: { “http”: require.resolve(“stream-http”) }’

[ng] - install ‘stream-http’

I have installed those modules, but nothing changed.
Then I tried to configure a custom webpack with webpack.config.js but I get another error on "Synthax" of a load_module.js (of common instead webpack)
